# Why does Git perform an automatic commit on one merge and not another?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I'm trying to understand why Git automatically does a commit for me when I merge in one scenario, but not in another.

**Scenario 1**:

We have just master with many commits and one or more tags.

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
rm -rf * # Plus removing a few .files other than the .git folder
git add -A
git commit -m "Created empty newbranch branch."
git merge tagname
```

**Scenario 2**:

Same as above as far as the state of the repo is concerned.

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
git merge tagname
```

When I perform scenario 1 and checkout the new branch, I will see all the commit messages plus two new ones at the top, the "Created empty newbranch branch." (which I put in myself) and another that says "Merge tag 'v1.02' into newbranch".

I've read the documentation (though probably never in the chapter-by-chapter order), but I don't understand why it should do an automatic commit for scenario 1 and none for scenario two.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it *did* do an automatic commit.

`git checkout --orphan newbranch` updates `HEAD` to tell git that you are on branch `newbranch`.  It does not create the branch.  The result is this:

```
$ git status
# On branch newbranch
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
[snip]
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/newbranch
$ git rev-parse HEAD
HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

If you now `git commit` something, the branch actually gets created.  Because `refs/heads/newbranch` did not exist when you do the "git commit", the "parent" of that new commit is empty, i.e., the branch now labels a commit that has no parent: a root commit.

Similarly, if you `git merge tagname` and the merge goes well, the commit happens, and the branch gets created.  Because this is a merge commit, it would normally (unless it's a fast-forward) have two parents: "the commit that was there before" and "what's there now".  But you told checkout, explicitly, that there should be "no commit there before".

Logically, then, the result is a single-parent commit, namely the one being merged-in.  It's performed as a fast-forward merge, setting `newbranch` to point to the same commit to which `tagname` points.

If you ask for a non-fast-forward merge, you get an error:

```
$ git merge --no-ff master
fatal: Non-fast-forward commit does not make sense into an empty head
```

This follows from the definitions of "root commit" and "merge commit": a root commit is a commit with no parents, and a "merge commit" is a commit with two or more parents.  It's simply not possible to have a merge commit with a single parent—that's just an ordinary non-merge commit!

Answer (score 0):

You're mergining into an empty branch so there is nothing to merge.

Comment: When I merge into the empty branch, there is something to merge. It does an automatic commit. When merging into the non-empty branch, it doesn't do this even though the tag I'm merging doesn't match the code that's already in that branch.